# Collectible figures with rotatable base

Tags: identify-this-game

First of all, I hope that this is the correct community for this question, otherwise I am happy to be corrected.

I am looking for certain figures (of a game I think/suppose) that I saw around the year 2000 in germany (country might be relevant). The only information I remember (and therefore might be incorrect) is:

- The prime feature to recognize/distinguish these figures should be the base they were standing on. It was black and white (or greyish - certainly not very colorful), consisted (at least primarily) of two pieces; an exterior "shell" and some interior hexagonal disk, which one could rotate. There was some sort of symbol (I think a number) on each corner of the hexagon and only one of these numbers were visible at the same time or at least spotlighted by the base. By turning the interior piece, one could change the number to I guess indicate some sort of strength or hp etc.

Here is a drawing that at least indicates what I am trying to describe:

[image]

- The figures are collectibles, i.e. the game does not come with a fixed set of figures that each player has, but one buys some sort of packs/single figures. At least thats how it seemed to me.
- The figures were in fantasy-style (some sort of beasts, dragons etc.)

Comment: It might be worth looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clix_(miniatures) and seeing I that jogs your memory.  What you're describing sounds like Clix but there are many versions.

Comment: @StartPlayer Yes, by now I am quite sure that the figures were using the clix system and by checking the various games using this system, it seems to me that mage knight fits the best. Since I cannot remember a single figure, I guess this is as far as I will get. Thanks for pointing out the clix system though. I was not aware of this being used for other games as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first Clix game,[Mage Knight](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/864/mage-knight) by WizKids, seems very similar to your description, and it came out in 2000.